# how to show images from a folder in sd card into grid view something like image gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

I need a tutorial where in I can get images from a folder to display in grid view  and then on click of the image in grid I can see full view and swipe functionality

any tutorial or code here please

thanks in advance

Comment: then where is your code? and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: you can say I tried a lot wd that code  find code here https://github.com/alvinsj/android-image-gallery problem is that when I use it in my project it does not coemup wd images

Comment: like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952653/how-to-test-push-notification-in-android-phonegap), you can accept the answer

Comment: Possibly duplicate follow following link             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619429/how-to-create-a-custom-gallery-having-images-of-a-particular-folder-on-sd-card          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775351/try-to-get-all-image-from-sdcard-to-show-in-gallery-view

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not hard to perform.
Find out your SD card folder path, scan and store image files and get image path in the SD card folder, get the bitmap from stored image path and put in to gridview. set gridview item selected listener to display image when click on a item.

There will not have a example code contains all the function you need. you can divide the problem to small ones, then try to solve it piece by piece. For example: solve scan image file from a folder first.

Answer (score -1):

1. If the code given in gitHub can not fetch your images then paste the
   path here which is used to fetch the images.
2. To set images in grid view, you already got the code. But now you
   want to slide the images one by one. Then I can give you a hint that
   use gallery view of android. It provides slider of small images. You
   need to change the resolution of images. You need to combine these 2
   views.